# C++ Display image sequence on an external display

Tags: c++, opencv

I am displaying an array of images into the external display. Following code is working, with every image of the array displayed when an Enter key is pressed.

The problem is when I would like to automate it (without key press). After the first imshow(), I tried to add a sleep, a wait or a thread... However, always the display is freezed, trying to display the first pixels of the first image.

How to display the images in the external display properly each, for example, 500ms?

```
while (i < (int)images.size())
{

        imshow("Image Window", images[i]);

        int key = waitKey(0);

        // Pressing enter generates the next image
        if (key == 13)
        {               
                cout << "image " << i + 1 << " OK" << endl << endl;
                i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, if you left waitKey(0), it simply waits forever for a key press (thats the default behaviour of waitKey for the parameter equal to 0)? If that is the problem, you can simply type waitKey(500) instead. It will make a delay of 500 ms between consecutive images.

Comment: you can use a timer to do this work fine

Comment: ohh both methods are working! Thank you very much